# Visual Studio Code Diseño

Tags: vscode

Estoy iniciando con la programación y probando editores de código, por ahora

> VSCode

creo que es el mejor. Pero tengo un problema y es que quiero modificar sus colores entre otras. Si alguien sabe que parte es la señalada en la foto para cambiarle el color y/o tiene una guía para poder sacarle el máximo provecho y configuración a dicho editor es bienvenida. Gracias de antemano[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y probaste en el sitio y con sus manuales?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta:

```
"editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground":"#252525"
```

Os resultará de ayuda esta página:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color